# Merge the "timeout" and "session-timeout" tags

Tags: support, stack-overflow, synonym-request

I think we can consolidate these tags; keep [timeout](/questions/tagged/timeout), and set [session-timeout](/questions/tagged/session-timeout) as synonym.

Comment: If you read each tag's wiki, you'll see they have virtually nothing to do with each other.

Comment: Yes, I see that now. I've been spending so much time looking at _session-timeout_ questions that I momentarily couldn't imagine the other uses of timeout.

Answer (score 11):

[timeout](/questions/tagged/timeout) and [session-timeout](/questions/tagged/session-timeout) are not synonyms, as the first doesn't imply there is any session involved. [session-timeout](/questions/tagged/session-timeout) is specific enough to exist as separate tag.

I cannot tell you if [timeout](/questions/tagged/timeout) is really helpful, but merging the tags is not the solution.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how they have much to do with each other aside from the word "timeout"

Session timeout could have something to do with a login and saving to a session etc, whereas a timeout can have to do any number of timers.